# Resource file shared as external file between solutions

Tags: c#, resources, external

I have two solutions, a solution named Server and a solution named Client.  The Server contains a resources file named Server.Properties.Resources.  That file is added to the Client solution as an **external** file.

When I debug inside Visual Studio, everything runs great.  When I run the deployed version, I get the error

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  
Make sure "Aexeo.DataLayer.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or 
linked into assembly "Core" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required 
are loadable and fully signed.
```

Is there a way to resolve this, maintaining the usage of the external file link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what exactly you are looking for :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839861

The problem is caused when you manually create satellite assemblies. Satellite assemblies should be named in such a way that it could automatically be called from the application. To solve the issue you can use Assembly linker  al.exe to link the assembly to the application properly.